# Black Screenshot android OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv

Currently I am using opencv what I want to happen is when the user presses the screen of course the screen/object from the displayed camera it will highlight all necessary/similar colors see:[Color-Blob-Detector](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection). [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVNYkpH66Hc) without the screenshot.

Below there is a small camera icon for triggering a screenshot (imagebutton), however when it screenshots the outcome of the picture is always black. What I wanted is when the necessary colors are being highlighted and I press the screenshot progmatically (which is the ImageButton) it will take the picture of the screen (including those highlighted objects) and save the image in the file.

I have also tried using the [camera control](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol) from opencv for taking a picture, but it is so hard for me to merge these two.

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String  TAG              = "OCVSample::Activity";

private boolean              mIsColorSelected = false;
private Mat                  mRgba;
private Scalar               mBlobColorRgba;
private Scalar               mBlobColorHsv;
private ColorBlobDetector    mDetector;
private Mat                  mSpectrum;
private Size                 SPECTRUM_SIZE;
private Scalar               CONTOUR_COLOR;


private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(Camera.this);
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public Camera() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.colorblobdetector);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), not working.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), working.");
    }


}





    public void camera_b(View v)
    {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "hellp.jpg";

        v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        OutputStream out = null;
        File imageFile = new File(path);

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            // choose JPEG format
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // manage exception
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // manage exception
        } finally {

            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception exc) {
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mDetector = new ColorBlobDetector();
        mSpectrum = new Mat();
        mBlobColorRgba = new Scalar(255);
        mBlobColorHsv = new Scalar(255);
        SPECTRUM_SIZE = new Size(200, 64);
        CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255,0,0,255);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int cols = mRgba.cols();
        int rows = mRgba.rows();

        int xOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
        int yOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() - rows) / 2;

        int x = (int)event.getX() - xOffset;
        int y = (int)event.getY() - yOffset;

        Log.i(TAG, "Touch image coordinates: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

        if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x > cols) || (y > rows)) return false;

        Rect touchedRect = new Rect();

        touchedRect.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0;
        touchedRect.y = (y>4) ? y-4 : 0;

        touchedRect.width = (x+4 < cols) ? x + 4 - touchedRect.x : cols - touchedRect.x;
        touchedRect.height = (y+4 < rows) ? y + 4 - touchedRect.y : rows - touchedRect.y;

        Mat touchedRegionRgba = mRgba.submat(touchedRect);

        Mat touchedRegionHsv = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(touchedRegionRgba, touchedRegionHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

        // Calculate average color of touched region
        mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(touchedRegionHsv);
        int pointCount = touchedRect.width*touchedRect.height;
        for (int i = 0; i < mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++)
            mBlobColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;

        mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(mBlobColorHsv);

        Log.i(TAG, "Touched rgba color: (" + mBlobColorRgba.val[0] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[1] +
                ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[2] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[3] + ")");

        mDetector.setHsvColor(mBlobColorHsv);

        Imgproc.resize(mDetector.getSpectrum(), mSpectrum, SPECTRUM_SIZE);

        mIsColorSelected = true;

        touchedRegionRgba.release();
        touchedRegionHsv.release();

        return false; // don't need subsequent touch events
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        if (mIsColorSelected) {
            mDetector.process(mRgba);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
            Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
            Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);

            Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
            colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

            Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
            mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);
        }

        return mRgba;
    }

    private Scalar converScalarHsv2Rgba(Scalar hsvColor) {
        Mat pointMatRgba = new Mat();
        Mat pointMatHsv = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, hsvColor);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL, 4);

        return new Scalar(pointMatRgba.get(0, 0));
    }
}
```

As you can see camera_b is where all screenshot happens.The XML for color blob detector: [ColorBlobXML](http://pastebin.com/MnykWaez) (I cannot paste XML code here)

[Image](https://i.imgsafe.org/4ea2261057.png) of the output. As you can see, It can take a screenshot of the button, not the expected [Image](https://i.imgsafe.org/4eb63a4fd5.png). (This [Image](https://i.imgsafe.org/4eb63a4fd5.png) is made by using power +vol down)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And in this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.colorblobdetector);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(0); //0 = back and 1 = frontal
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), not working.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), working.");
    }
```

Comment: The setCameraIndex(0) didn't help either.